# MVC Layout.cshtml control

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller

I am making a MVC application using Entity Framework. In my database I store much information (also about my users). I want my navbar (in Layout) to be different for different users (basing on entities). Normally I pass my entities in controller, but how do I do this with a shared Layout?

Comment: You can set a viewbag entry(based on the current user type) and check that in your layout to show different navars

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use child actions:

```
public class FooController : Controller
{
    ...

    [AllowAnonymous]
    [ChildActionOnly]
    public ActionResult Navbar()
    {
        var navbar = // retrieve navbar data
        return PartialView("_Navbar", navbar);
    }
}
```

The controller you put this in doesn't matter. You'll just need to reference it when you call the child action. For example, in your layout:

```
@Html.Action("Navbar", "Foo")
```

Finally, just create a partial view to render the navbar. In this example, that would be `_Navbar.cshtml`. The partial view can utilize a model, and the layout will remain completely agnostic.

Comment: If you call a child action in the layout wouldn't you need it in every controller that uses the layout?

Comment: No. The second parameter is the controller reference.